# Can't load local xml file in IE

Tags: html, xml, vbscript

I have created a HTML file to load local XML file and read contents of it. Here is the code I am using to read local file

```
 Function Loader(Location)
    Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.load(Location)
    Response.Write xmlSet(xmlDoc.xml,Location)
 End function
```

If this file is in local file system it is perfectly loading all the xml files. But If i put this file in FTP and try to load local XML file this is not working. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: `Response.Write`? What's the environment, IE or ASP? May need to see function that named `xmlSet`, so I'm confused :) Please explain us.

Comment: I am using response.write to call a javascript function.(only in only IE). xmlSet is a javascript function with two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. Its to prevent security issues.